# What is Location based testing in Software Testing field?

Tags: testing

Can anyone explain about what is Location based testing?. Do we have list of tools available for this testing? if means please suggest some tools.

Comment: This may help: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/how-to-test-a-location-based-application

Answer (score -1):

Location based testing is testing apps that deals with location of the device or whose functionality depends on the location. Generally in mobile devices. eg. rental car apps like Uber.
I'm not aware of specific tools but you can use location fakers like Lockito for android to get your testing done.

Edit : Here is a article that you can refer to
http://www.testingdiaries.com/location-based-mobile-testing/